# Converting String Date to DateTimePST(String) and DateTimeLocal(String) using Offset?

Tags: java, string, datetime, timezone, timezone-offset

I have three parameters, UTCTime and two offsets all three as strings, I need to convert them as below

```
Input: 
    String UTCTime = "2020-09-29 16:06:00";
    String PSTOffset = "-07:00";
    String LocalOffset = "-04:00";

Output Expected:
        LocalTime = "2020-09-29 12:06:00"
        PSTTime = "2020-09-29 09:06:00"
```

I tried doing something like this

```
    OffsetDateTime OffsetLocalTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(String.format("%sT%sZ",UTCTime.split(" ")[0],UTCTime.split(" ")[1]));
    OffsetLocalTime = OffsetLocalTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of(LocalOffset));

    OffsetDateTime OffsetPSTTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(String.format("%sT%sZ",UTCTime.split(" ")[0],UTCTime.split(" ")[1]));
    OffsetPSTTime = OffsetPSTTime.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of(PSTOffset));

    String LocalTime = String.format("%s %s",OffsetLocalTime.toString().substring(0,OffsetLocalTime.toString().lastIndexOf('-')).split("T")[0],OffsetLocalTime.toString().substring(0,OffsetLocalTime.toString().lastIndexOf('-')).split("T")[1]);
    String PSTTime = String.format("%s %s",OffsetPSTTime.toString().substring(0,OffsetPSTTime.toString().lastIndexOf('-')).split("T")[0],OffsetPSTTime.toString().substring(0,OffsetPSTTime.toString().lastIndexOf('-')).split("T")[1]);

    System.out.println("OffsetLocalTime: "+OffsetLocalTime);
    System.out.println("OffsetPSTTime: "+ OffsetPSTTime);

    System.out.println("LocalTime: "+ LocalTime);
    System.out.println("PSTTime: "+ PSTTime);

    Actual Output:

    OffsetLocalTime: 2020-09-29T12:06-04:00
    OffsetPSTTime: 2020-09-29T09:06-07:00
    LocalTime: 2020-09-29 12:06
    PSTTime: 2020-09-29 09:06
```

I am missing out seconds and this seems to be an inefficient way beacuse i do not need 'T' or offset in my output and i am getting rid of them. I am not sure if this question is already asked. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that when you have only an offset, you don't have enough information to know whether DST is in effect or not.  In your example, you have `-07:00` - which is actually the PDT offset.  PST is `-08:00`.  For the date given, -7 is correct, but for other dates it would be -8.  Thus you should use `ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles")` (assuming USA) if possible.  It will apply the correct offset depending on the date being converted.  Likewise, you might want to also use `ZoneId.systemDefault()` instead of a fixed local offset.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Thanks for reminder about the day light savings, I will keep that in mind. I am actually getting time in milliseconds, month, day and year all in UTC (I am putting them together to get [yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss] a UTC date)  and based on two offsets calculating the Local time and Pacific Time

Comment: Sure.  All I'm saying is - don't hardcode the offsets, because they can change.  Use zone identifiers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the given date-time string, `2020-09-29 16:06:00` does not have zone-offset information, it needs to be first parsed into `LocalDateTime` and then the `LocalDateTime` can be converted into `OffsetDateTime`.

Do it as follows:

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Define the formatter
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

        // Given date-time
        String localTimeUTC = "2020-09-29 16:06:00";

        // Get OffsetDateTime from the given date-time string
        OffsetDateTime odtUTC = LocalDateTime.parse(localTimeUTC, formatter).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);

        // OffsetDateTime with an Zone-Offset of -7 hours
        OffsetDateTime odtAtOffsetMinus7Hours = odtUTC.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7));
        System.out.println(odtAtOffsetMinus7Hours.format(formatter));

        // OffsetDateTime with an Zone-Offset of -4 hours
        OffsetDateTime odtAtOffsetMinus4Hours = odtUTC.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.ofHours(-4));
        System.out.println(odtAtOffsetMinus4Hours.format(formatter));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2020-09-29 09:06:00
2020-09-29 12:06:00
```

**Note:** Instead of using `ZoneOffset.ofHours(-7)`, you can also use `ZoneOffset.of("-07:00")` depending on what (number/string) you have got to work with.

Comment: @OleV.V. - Thanks for bringing it to my attention. I was so absorbed in writing one complete solution that I did not think of alternatives . Now, I've used it as a note at the end.

Comment: Is there any other simple way to calculate Local and Pacific Time to calculate from UTC date using the two offsets?

Comment: @VenkateshGotimukul - Whatever I've posted in the answer is already the simplest way (you have to use just one function, `withOffsetSameInstant`). I can post other ways but believe me, they will be using more than one functions.